# add or substract a number to each word of a line in Vim

Tags: vim

I want a substract a positif number to each word of the current line. I know the Ctrl-X shortcut, but sadly it applies only to the first word if I use it in a visual selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, a solution using a trick taken from here : [reverse the order of words of a line in Vim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M98nfH4QH9g) exploding the current line into words, with the command 's/ +/\r/g`

for example, if I want to substract 3 to each word, i will register the following macro in the register w
qwOjok:s/ +/\r/g{jv}3v}Jkddq

That solution could be improved, because using the macro one multiple lines does not work. I tried to used a mark instead of { to jump, but it does not prevent to mix the lines